# Geofencing: Debugger shows value of Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER equal to 0

Tags: android, android-geofence, android-debug

I am trying to implement geofencing in my app but I do not understand why the debugger is showing the value of Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER equal to 0.

Below is my onHandleIntent. If I am understanding correctly then if the device is already inside the geofence then

```
geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
```

should be true, as the value of geofenceTransition is shown 1 by the debugger, but since Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER is equal to 0 (??) the if block doesn't execute. I am testing on a MI Redmi android device. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in geofencing event");
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Entered geofence",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Toast.makeText(this,"Not entered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(geofenceTransition));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure after over a year you have already either already fixed this - or given up and moved into property development!

Of course, looking at com.google.android.gms.location code, `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` is a constant set to 1.

So either you have misread something, the old version of com.google.android.gms.location code had a bug, or else the inequality is elsewhere.

The only other cause of this issue is be that you aren't setting an initial trigger when creating your `GeofencingRequest`.

```
GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
```

If you have set the trigger incorrectly (i.e. to INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT), your Intent handler will only be fired for a that trigger and so `if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)` will never be true.